# addEventListener not working

Tags: javascript

Not finding any error with this code:
But it is not giving the result. Can anyone help?

```
<script>
    var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
    btn.addEventListener('click',toggleDiv,false);

    function toggleDiv(x){
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("aDiv");    
        if(x.style.height === "0px"){
            x.style.transition = "height 0.5s ease-in 0s";  
            x.style.height = "auto";        
        }else{
            x.style.transition = "height 0.5s ease-in 0s";
            x.style.height = "0px"; 
        }   
    }
</script>
```

Comment: see first answer, btn is an Array of elements, not a single btn element

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code.

```
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

function toggleDiv(x){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("aDiv");    
    if(x.style.height === "0px"){
    x.style.transition = "height 0.5s ease-in 0s";  
    x.style.height = "auto";        
    }else{
    x.style.transition = "height 0.5s ease-in 0s";
    x.style.height = "0px"; 
    }   
    }

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', toggleDiv, false);
}
```

Hope it works for you.